# Is Vrindavan in India the same village which is described in Bhagavatam?

Tags: krishna, history, bhagavata-purana, geography, vrindavana

The [10th Canto](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10) of Shrimad Bhagavatam (Bhagavata Purana) describes the pastimes of Lord Krishna in detail. The pastimes of Lord Krishna are also summarized in [KṚṢṆA, The Supreme Personality of Godhead](https://www.vedabase.com/en/kb) by Prabhupada.

My question centers around the following two pastimes of the Lord:

1. [Subduing of Kaliya](https://www.vedabase.com/en/kb/16)
2. [Indra's wrath on Vrindavan](https://www.vedabase.com/en/kb/25)

Krishna was born in Mathura in the prison house of Kamsa. Vasudev immediately after the birth of Krishna took Him to Gokul.

Due to the atrocities of Kamsa; the inhabitants of Gokul left for Vrindavan and Krishna stayed there in a place which is today called Nandagram.

So regardless of where Krishna stayed during pastime with Kaliya or Indra (He was mostly in NanagGram according to me):

- Nandagram to Vrindavan distance: approx 45km.
- Nandagram to Govardhan: approx 29km.

So when Krishna was caught by Kaliya; Yashoda and all others came running to a place which is today called Kaliya ghat and is approx 45km from Nandagram.

A similar thing happened during Govardhan Lila of the lord; Govardhan is approx 29 km from Nandagram.

**How did they travel so swiftly to such a far distance?**

Considering that Krishna incarnated approximately 5000 years ago; I don't think they would have had very huge bodies or bodily abilities in comparison to us.

**Is today's Vrindavan, the one in the Mathura district of Uttar Pradesh, the same which is mentioned in Bhagavatam?**

Comment: The more parsimonious explanation might be that Nandgaon is the place that isn't authentic.  At least my experience of Nandgaon is that it was a place filled with con artists, but then again that's just the nature of the Kali Yuga.

Comment: Or maybe these areas were wider in those times than current time.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think the arial distance is less..Vasudevji went Gokula and came back to Krishn Janmbhumi i.e. 12*2=24 km on foot that too in night 12 and in worse weather conditions...walking 24 kms in night and worse weather in 3-4 hrs is a difficult task, so i think distance was less..places might be same but current ways r not the same..